# How to export Excel with Hindi script to CSV file?

Tags: excel, csv, export

I would like to know how to export an excel spreadsheet which contains, say a table of Hindi(for that matter any non-english) script words into a CSV file? I tried 'Save As' --> comma delimited, but the characters weren't preserved. When I opened the *.csv file, all i saw as ?????? characters.

Thanks, 
Sameer

Comment: In my Excel 2000 you can use    save as Unicode    to save as a tab delimited utf16 file

Comment: Verify that whatever program you opened your csv file in is set to the correct character set as well.